# Peewee: getting records where a given string startswith() the content of a field

Tags: python, peewee

I was writing a statement containing this where-clause in peewee:

```
.where(some_string.startswith(Record.text_field))
```

This expression raises `TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not CharField`. `some_string` is just a normal string, therefore `startswith` is the method from the standard lib, not the one that is provided by peewee.

So it is clear, why that happens, but what is the correct way to write this expression?

Answer (score -1):

You've either got things very backwards or do not understand how Peewee works. If you have a string ("some_string") how do you expect the Python interpreter to perform a startswith test on a value stored in a db column?

The correct approach is to use `Record.text_field.startswith(some_string)` which translates into

```
WHERE "record"."text_field" LIKE 'value in some string%'
```

Comment: As I wrote, it is clear why the error is raised. Of course it cannot work that way. But your proposed solution seems to be the one that is backwards. The `text_field` should be a prefix of `some_string` not the other way around. `a.startswith(b)` does not equal `b.startswith(a)`.